# 'cell' input issue with fprintf() ----MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, date, struct, printf

I currently have an issue in implementing:

```
fprintf( '%6s %12s %12s\n','Date',  'res1',  'res2');
fprintf('%6s %12.8f %12.8f\n',o,A.');
```

*Error*:

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

As a matter of fact:

```
o is <6*1 cell> of dates mm/dd/yyyy
```

whereas

```
A is <2*6 double> of numbers
```

Hence my interrogation:

**1/** Do solutions exist to handle this issue as well as export the screen results from Matlab to **data.csv** at some specified file path on my C:\?

Thanks

Comment: MATLAB tells you exactly what the problem is: convert `o` from cell to e.g. a string array. Then to save it as file, you'll have to specify the file identifier `fid`. This all is very well described in the help page of `fprintf`.

Comment: `num2str(cell2mat())` is messing up the results, maybe due to the format `mm/dd/yyyy` that adds more rows to the char type (fyi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes a for loop is the easiest:

```
fprintf( '%6s %12s %12s\n','Date',  'res1',  'res2');
for ii=1:length(o)
  fprintf('%6s %12.8f %12.8f\n',o{ii},A(:,ii));
end
```

Comment: Excellent dude for this accurate tip. Cheers!